# SF API QueryResult throws error

Tags: soap-api

need help with an issue.  Here is the java code sample.

String soqlQuery = "SELECT Id FROM ....";
QueryResult qResult = connection.query(soqlQuery);

This throws up the following exception:
Incompatible type 'class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult' specified as xsi:type. It must be a subclass of 'class com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult'

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, this issue got resolved automatically when I restarted the server application.  Must be something to with the container and caching.